# understanding the syntax for rtsp URL's

Tags: vlc, rtsp

By trial and error I was able to display the feed from an RTSP WiFi cam in VLC using the URL:

```
rtsp://192.168.2.33:554?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp
```

However all the examples I find use something like:

```
rtsp://192.168.2.33:554/user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp
```

with the `/` instead of the `?`. The `/` does not work for me. VLC can not open the stream.  Does anyone know what the difference is?

Answer (score 3):

Question mark is used in URI as a separator of a path to the resource and query arguments. Per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

```
    foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
    \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
     |           |            |            |        |
  scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

And in [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> The path is terminated by the first question mark ("?") or number sign ("#") character, or by the end of the URI.

So your first example is correct.

The second one (without `?`) is wrong, because it combines query arguments into a path to the requested resource.

---

As a side note: browsers (at least current versions of Chrome or Firefox) will automatically change:

```
http://192.168.2.33:554?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp
```

into:

```
http://192.168.2.33:554/?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However VLC responds with VLC is unable to open the MRL `rtsp://192.168.2.33:554/?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp` while `rtsp://192.168.2.33:554?user=admin&password=&channel=2&stream=1.sdp` works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rtsp://user:password@ip.of.your.device/
```

This should give you the first channel at least, after that it can be dependant on the device as to the syntax for the rest of it.

```
rtsp://user:password@ip.of.your.device/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1
```

works for mine but your mileage may vary.